# c#: Finding Bugs: if(false)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've just found a bug in my program (after some amount of debugging and tearing my hair)

```
bool first = true;

foreach (RdAbstractNode node in listNodes)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        // do stuff (does not change first)
    }
    // do more stuff (does not change first)
}
```

As you can see `first`is always `true` - never changed. So `if(!first)` is basically `if(false)`.
The compiler did not generate a warning although it is set to level 4 (highest level).

How can I find similar `if(false)` errors?

I'm using VS 2010, .Net 4.0 compiler, project setting .Net 2.0

Comment: your `//do stuff` could do something that could flip `first` but I have seen Resharper show warnings about stuff that's always false or true.

Comment: or rather, `// do more stuff` would need to be the one that flipped the variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) you'll get warnings like this

[image]

Comment: +1 for recommending Resharper. It's a pricey add-on for some, but it is invaluable in examples like this.

Comment: Is there anything free or do i just have to spend the 42€ for the academic license?

Comment: @Pretzel: "Invaluable" is a stretch.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio everyday then it's a valuable tool and it's well worth the 42€. But they do have a 30 day trial so you can take your time to decide.

Comment: R# is sweet, but unit tests are free and will catch logic errors R# would miss.

Comment: I've just installed ReSharper. I have to admit: I like it :) I'll consider buying it. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Note that if you put `first = !first;` after "// do more stuff", then ReSharper is smart enough to stop warning you.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of a compiler feature that will help you - you need unit tests.

Comment: The compiler does warn about unassigned variables. It does know if a variable has a constant value. But it does not even warn about `if(false)`

Comment: @Simon Ottenhaus: Unassigned variables are very different than what you have here.

Comment: I get a compilation warning if I have an if(false) block with code in it.  If there is only a comment in it, the compiler appears to be optimizing the block out without a warning.


I agree with @dahlbyk: you probably want to use code coverage analysis or a static analyzer.  If you want to know why this isn't a warning, this article may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/03/danger-will-robinson.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I agree  that Resharper is a good tool to have, but i'd like to add that i think this demonstrates a reason NOT to use this construct.

An alternative might be:

**EDIT:**

```
//.net 4.0
    var firstNode = listNodes.First(); 
       //do something special for first. 

    foreach(var node in listNodes.Skip(1)) 
    {
       //do something for the rest.
    }

//.net 2.0
using (IEnumerator<RdAbstractNode> enumerator = listNodes.GetEnumerator();)
{
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
       return;

    RdAbstractNode first = enumerator.Current; 
    //do something with first
    while(enumerator.MoveNext()) 
    { 
       RdAbstractNode currentNode = enumerator.Current;
       //do something with the node.
    } 
}
```

We often find ourselves needing to have some kind of special handling for the first element, sometimes it's better to change the logic and make all the processing uniform.
If we can't then i always prefer to clearly separate the special case handling from the rest of the elements instead of nesting it.

Comment: mm..missed that - but can be done the long(er) way:
`var enumerator =  listNodes.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
var first = enumerator.Current;
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
  //do something with enumerator.Current
}`

Comment: Note that the `IEnumerator<RdAbstractNode>` should be disposed. And if appropriate you should handle the first `MoveNext()` call returning `false`.

Comment: Thanks @dahlbyk - added the missing handling

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will warn you of obvious things like unreachable code based on a constant value in the if statement - e.g. "if (false)". However, because the variable could be altered it won't do in this case unfortunately.